# JSON 2D key value Response Text into Drop Down

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I'm getting Response string same as like this.

```
var txtResponse = "{"Tom":{"Given Name":"Tom","Employee Number":"21"},"Sam":{"Given Name":"Sam","Employee Number":"23"},"Jack":{"Given Name":"Jack","Employee Number":"19"}}";
```

Need to put this on html drop down and assign Text as 'Given Name' and value as 'Employee Number' of each employee by java script.

I have used this to assign values to drop down for other array.

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectelement");
var optionContent = document.createElement("option");
            optionContent.textContent = "";
            optionContent.value = "";
            select.appendChild(optionContent);
```

can you please help me to assign 'textContent' and 'value' from above response through loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the keys in the json object like the following,

```
var txtResponse = '{"Tom":{"Given Name":"Tom","Employee Number":"21"},"Sam":{"Given Name":"Sam","Employee Number":"23"},"Jack":{"Given Name":"Jack","Employee Number":"19"}}';

var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(txtResponse);
var select = document.getElementById("selectelement");

Object.keys(jsonResponse).forEach(key => {
   var optionContent = document.createElement("option");
   optionContent.textContent = jsonResponse[key]['Given Name'];
   optionContent.value = jsonResponse[key]['Employee Number'];
   select.appendChild(optionContent);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let res:any='{"Tom":{"Given Name":"Tom","Employee Number":"21"},"Sam":{"Given Name":"Sam","Employee Number":"23"},"Jack":{"Given Name":"Jack","Employee Number":"19"}}';

this.res=JSON.parse(this.res);
    console.log('res==',this.res)
    let select=document.getElementById("selectelement");
    for(let el in this.res){
      let optionContent=document.createElement("option");
      optionContent.innerHTML=this.res[el]['Given Name'];
      optionContent.value=this.res[el]['Employee Number'];
      select.appendChild(optionContent);
     }
```

```html
<select id="selectelement"> </select>
```